# javascript implicit global variables

Tags: javascript, variables, global, implicit

I tried this code on the firefox console and it throws a ReferenceError:

```
var func = function (){
  bim = "implicit global";
};
alert(bim);
ReferenceError: bim is not defined
```

Historically in javascript if you set a variable without declaring it (using the "var" keyword) that variable would be defined in the outermost LexicalEnvironment (that is: window object on a browser).
So why can't i access the variable from outside the function? I used to be able to do this. I know it's not the best practice, but i want to know what changed. I read about "let" and "const" on ES6 but does this mean that implicit global variables dont' exist anymore?. I'm not using "strict mode", just typing it directly on the console.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You didn't run the function.

Comment: You need to execute the function then it wuold be in global scope.

Comment: A more accurate error message in this specific case would be "bim is not defined... yet"

Comment: Thanks for all your replies! I knew i was missing something obvious; i'm a little rusty on my javascript. I'll go back writing JS more often.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting this error is because you have not executed the function, the correct way to write this would be:

```
var func = function(){
    bim = "implicit global";
};

func();
alert(bim);
```